# Error on commit changes with Git and Intellij

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I use Intellij and Git as Version Control System. I work on a specific project andI have created a branch on which I have committed changes several times. Now I try once again to commit changes but it becomes impossible because of an occurring error which I cannot identify. I receive initially a message: “commit failed with errors” and following a message : Your branch is ahead of master by 3 commits. #Untracked files# Use git add  to include in what will be committed.

What can be the cause of that?  What should I actually do?

I receive a prompt as well to move the files failed to be committed to another changelist. But how will this affect the project?

Comment: finally I didi a revert on the files failed to commit initially and then I managed to commit them successfully and to merge them to master branch.

Answer (score 0):

It just says that you haven't added or staged any files / modifications for commit. I don't know about Intellij's git integration, but do the equivalent of `git add` ( might be worded add, stage, etc.) and then try the commit. Or from command line, go to the repo and do a `git add` on the files / modifications you want to commit.